# Couldn't print random switch cases string inside a for loop

Tags: c#

Hit everyone! I'm still learning C# and I would like to print different string for each loop based on the switch cases.

```cs
static Random rand = new Random();
static void Main(string[] args){
    string someString = "";
    int someRandom = rand.Next(4);
    switch(someRandom) {
        case 0:
            someString = "Woa";
            break;
        case 1:
            someString = "Waa";
            break;
        case 2:
            someString = "Wee";
            break;
        case 3:
            someString = "Wow!";
            break;
    }
    int someCount = 5;
    for (int someInt = 0; someInt < someCount; someInt++) {
        Console.WriteLine(someString);
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

**What it should do:** display random string each loop from the switch.

**What it actually does:** Selects case randomly and prints the same case in each loop.

I couldn't produce a random string, why is that? I tried adding `someRandom = rand.Next(4)` inside the for loop but still produces same.

I already tried searching but couldn't find an answer that could solve my problem.

Comment: You need to put the `switch` _inside_ the `for` loop. Right now, the code picks one random work, then prints it 5 times. You need to pick a new random word each time in the `for` loop, before printing it. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are only setting somestring once, and then printing it a bunch. You should put the switch statement in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the random number (and set the `someString` variable) inside the loop, otherwise you only pick one random number and then display it multiple times in the loop.

Here's an example but with some slightly better names (IMO):

```
static Random rand = new Random();

static void Main()
{
    int count = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        string output;

        switch(rand.Next(4)) 
        {
            case 0:
                output = "Woa";
                break;
            case 1:
                output = "Waa";
                break;
            case 2:
                output = "Wee";
                break;
            case 3:
                output = "Wow!";
                break;
            default:
                output = "This shouldn't happen";
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```